# how can i solve this?Python bots

Tags: python, youtube, bots

i am trying to learn about bots, so i tried to make a basic youtube bot, but it stops after 50 views, how can i solve this, i got this so far

```
import os
import time
import webbrowser

cycles=int(input("Please input the times of cycles you want to run: "))
num=int(input("Please input the number of pages you want to open in each cycle: "))
delay=int(input("Please input the time delay for restarting the cycle: "))
website = input("Please input your web: ")

hits=cycles*num
print("You will access " +website+ " " , hits, " times")

for i in range(cycles):
    for i in range(num):
        webbrowser.open(website)
    time.sleep(delay)
```

Comment: Probably the problem is that youtube does not allow that frequent requests.

Comment: buy some proxy servers to work as many users.

Comment: Furas, where can i buy proxy servers and how can i use them, thanks in advance